# Need to find out the name of the graphics card and and if driver is installed?

Tags: linux-mint

I am using Mint 12 on a lenovo machine. How do I find the exact name of my graphics card to download and install driver? Also is there any way to check if the driver is already installed or not?

Comment: Try running `lspci`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**One way:**

Install the lshw tool with `sudo apt-get install lshw lshw-gtk`

Invoke the tool in the terminal with: `sudo lshw`

Answer (score 13):

The easiest way is to use `lspci`:

```
lspci | grep VGA
```

On my system, this returns:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT216 [Quadro FX 880M] (rev a2)
```

---

To check which driver is loaded run this for NVIDIA cards:

```
lsmod | grep nv
```

and this for ATI cards (will return nothing if the proprietary driver is not loaded):

```
lsmod | grep radeon
```

Answer (score 4):

I went to software manager and installed "Sysinfo".  Once installed you can open it and click on Hardware and a box will appear in the upper right-hand corner that will give you options of details on your Motherboard,Graphics card,Sound card and Network.  I have used terminal before but for those of us with bad memories, the graphical interface is very handy.